# xPath working for only one of multiple div tags found at the same level

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, selenium-chromedriver

Writing tests with Selenium webdriver in C#. I absolutely can't understand why only the first in a list of (same-level) div elements can be identified with xPath.
I have this html, I have inspected two elements on the page, two different divs. I managed to copy just the text of the first element, by running this SIMPLE code:

```
IWebElement chapterElement = webDriver.FindElement(By.XPath("/html/body/div[3]/main/div[2]/div[3]/article/div[1]"));
```

...after which I can just type:
`chapterElement.Text` to find out the inner text.

And the other one is another div, at the same level as the first, the xPath I just copied from the HTML (copy entire xPath):

```
       IWebElement chapterElement = webDriver.FindElement(By.XPath("/html/body/div[3]/main/div[2]/div[3]/article/div[2]"));
```

... and it doesn't fail, but it doesn't copy the text also, the text is "" (empty string).

The only differences between the two divs are:

- the last segment in the path: div[1] versus div[2].
- the second div is actually hidden from the page (probably because it lacks the class "chapter_visible"), but does show up completely in the html with Inspect!

In case this helps, I'm gonna say

```
"/html/body/div[3]/main/div[2]/div[3]/article/div[1]"
```

corresponds with:

```
<div class="chapter chapter chapter_visible" data-chapterno="0" data-chapterid="5e8798266cee070006f5a3d1" style="display: block;">
    <h1>some text</h1>
    <div class="chapter__content"><p>some text</p>
<p>some text</p>
<p>some text</p>
<ul>
<li>some text</li>
<li>some text</li>
<li>some text.</li>
</ul></div>
</div>
```

and
`"/html/body/div[3]/main/div[2]/div[3]/article/div[2]"` (the second xPath)
corresponds to the following (as is located at the same level as the first):

```
<div class="chapter chapter" data-chapterno="1" data-chapterid="5e8798436cee070006f5a3d2">
    <h1>some text</h1>
    <div class="chapter__content"><p>some text</p>
<p><strong>some text</strong></p>
<p>some text.</p>
<p>some text</p>
<p>some text</p></div>
</div>
```

This is my first experience playing around with xPath, a bit disappointed because I just copied the xPath, I didn't even write it manually. It was supposed to be fast and straightforward, right? Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
IWebElement chapterElement = webDriver.FindElement(By.XPath("//div[@class='chapter chapter']"));
```

Can u try this?

if you want get_attribute

```
IWebElement chapterElement = webDriver.FindElement(By.XPath("//div[@class='chapter chapter']")).GetAttribute("attribute_name");
```

Comment: I have an idea, could this be related to the element not being displayed on the page? Maybe .Text just returns the displayed text, how do I return the inner html? Checking this assumption now.. (trying element.GetAttribute("innerHTML");)

Comment: Ok this actually worked, the problem was .Text is not suitable for elements that are hidden, i should have tried with .GetAttribute("innerHTML") and also your relative xpath was great. Thank you! If you could please edit in this suggestion to use .GetAttribute instead of .Text I will mark your answer.

Comment: Would you please give feedback on whether the code is working correctly?

Comment: Sorry, I just accepted your answer. This worked great! Thank you.